# Codeigniter Url Problem on Server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some problem in codeigniter url segment problem in server..

In local server my web url is `http:localhost/test/index.php/user/userGetData/3`..if we want to get the 3 from url in controller function . 
then we use `$this->uri->?segment(3);` it works.

But when uploaded on server we use url rewriting

`$routes['getData'] = 'user/userGetData/$1';` and refresh the page after this          change, server url look like  http://www.test.com/getData/3

in controller function `userGetData()` `$this->uri->segment(3);` doesn't work.

How to fix this problem and same case in all function?

Comment: did you try `$this->uri->segment(2)` with your new route?

Comment: how to fix this problem in route file..without any changes in contorller functions...

Comment: if you just want to get the id from url you can also use this in your controller userGetData($id)... in $id you can received 3 .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$this->uri->?segment(3)` it's work?

First, you need to change `$config['base_url']`

Use `$this->uri->segment(2)` to get data.